# Addition Theorem Simplify

Tags: trigonometry

Could you help me use addition theorem formulas to express the following trig. function in terms of $t$ when $\tan (a/2)=t$ ($t$ cannot $=1$)

$1$) $\cos a$

so far I have $\tan^2 (a/2)=\dfrac{1-\cos a}{1+\cos a}$

Comment: can you use $$\LaTeX$$ please?

Comment: Google Wierstrass substitution (or is it Weierstrass?)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
\begin{align*}
\cos 2x=\cos(x+x)&=\cos x\cos x-\sin x\sin x\\
&=\cos^2 x -\sin^2 x\\
&=2\cos^2 x -1\\
&=\frac{2}{\sec^2 x}-1&&\text{since }\cos x=\frac{1}{\sec x}\\
&=\frac{2}{1+\tan^2 x}-1&&\text{since }1+\tan^2x=\sec^2 x\\
&=\frac{1-\tan^2 x}{1+\tan^2 x}
\end{align*}
Now take $2x=a$, and $\tan(a/2)=t$.